# Ionic2 phone call doesnt work on ios but on android (emu and devices)

Tags: ios, ionic2

In my HTML file I am using a sliding-item and inside the options a button that calls a function:

```
<button secondary *ngIf="post.telefone" (click)="callIT('tel:'+post.telefone)">
  <ion-icon name="call"></ion-icon>
  Call
</button>
```

In the js file I have the function callIt() like:

```
callIT(passedNumber) {
  window.location = passedNumber;
}
```

In my config.xml I added these line of code:

```
<access origin="*"/>
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes"/>
```

This is working for android for both the emulator and on a device. In ios the call functionality isn`t working at all. Thanks to all for help